# Facebook SDK causing 'appDebug' error

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, gradle, sdk

I am trying to incorporate Facebook SDK and Parse SDK, but Android Studio is giving me errors at compile time.

Here is my error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.4.jar')
}
```

Similar post: [Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702234/android-studio-c-program-files-java-jdk1-8-0-51-bin-java-exe-finished-with) [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455315/build-gradle-issues-when-using-facebook-sdk-4-0-0-and-parse-com-libraries-in-and) but not a duplicate, as these solutions didn't work for me. I have tried adding 
this

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

But this doesn't work, and honestly isn't a good solution. When I remove facebook sdk, my app compiles no problem, but with it nothing works. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own question:

Facebook SDK provides a bolts library within it (at least the 4.+.+ does), so the error was coming from compiling Bolts twice.

Here is the new build.gradle file (innermost)

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.4.jar')
}
```

Also upgraded top-level build.gradle to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'
}
```